# How to direct a link to another tab in .Md files

Tags: r

I have used the below to go to facebook page in my md file. Now the link is opening in the samepage. How can I make it to open in another tab

```
Visit the full-page app at [Go to application](https://www.facebook.com/){target="_blank"}
```

In RMD file this is happening. But not in .md file it is not. May I know the reason?

Comment: Try to put a colon before `target` (see [here](https://www.mydigitaltoolbox.pro/blog/markdown-kramdown-link-new-tab/)). Otherwise, use standard html ("a" tag).

Comment: Nope. I do not think in .md file this is possible. We can do this in .Rmd file